# Store data in Chrome Extension (permanent, not in localStorage)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filesystems

I am creating a Chrome Extension where I need to store `favorites` of a particular user in an array, which is in turn saved in a file so that the data can be retrieved the next time. I tried writing the code using `localStorage`, but this data can be erased by a user easily.

Is there any way I can save the data in files from where data cannot be deleted?
 If yes, please provide the detailed steps.

Comment: Save the data in a file, or in a database server-side.

Comment: Seems to me your answer will be found here -> https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: @daddygames, unfortunately, this is similar to local storage, where the data can be deleted by the user.

Comment: @Striped, how? (I am a newbie, please provide detailed steps if possible)

Comment: I will certainly not code for you. Look at google for Node API, mongodb. And post a new question if you need some help when you'll try something ;)

Comment: @DimiAnsari it's unethical to force storage on a user without the option for them to delete. Plus, it's impossible. The option I link to allows your settings to sync with the google account which is about the easiest you can get from developer perspective.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to build a server-side component that stores the data and even then, without permanent local storage, you cannot always auto-detect the user to pull down their data. The user would need an identifier of some sorts (username/password, token, or similar).

Comment: "*Is there any way I can save the data in files from where data cannot be deleted*" - Yes, it's called *uploading to your own server*. Users have full control over their machines and there's nothing you can do to prevent them from deleting a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using an external database, then i would recommend you using the chrome storage as it works through all your devices, given that you use `sync`

## JavaScript

```
if(chrome && chrome.storage){
    chrome.storage.sync.get('itemName', function(result){
        //I am asynchronous, so be cautious in the order order in which you render stuff.
        //I also return an object {...} rather than a string, so don't JSON.parse() me
        const item = result['itemName'];
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

## manifest.json

```
{ ...,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  ...
}
```